# Angular Material SVG icon - path issue

Tags: angular, svg, angular-material, http-status-code-404

Maybe it's silly, but I've been a long time lost with this and I would need some help.

I have custom SVG icons that work well in the development environment. They are declared like this:

```
this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
  "icon1",
  this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/images/icon1.svg")
);
this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
  "icon2",
  this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("../assets/images/icon2.svg")
);
```

When I publish the application in production with **ng build --prod** the icons do not work. In the log you see the following:

*GET https://www.example.kkk/assets/images/icon1.svg 404 (Not Found)
main.b88c0c542471bd40dec4.js:1 Error retrieving icon: Http failure response for https://www.example.kkk/assets/images/icon1.svg*

In the development environment the application runs at http://localhost:4200 and in production runs at https://www.example.kkk/app. Either way, **app** disappears from the url.

I've tried with

```
this.matIconRegistry.addSvgIcon(
  "icon1",
  this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("/assets/images/icon1.svg")
);
```

but it does not work either.

My configuration is the following:
*Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.9.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.2*

Any clue that helps solve it? Thanks!

Comment: use "assets/images/icon1.svg".

Comment: Had you set <base> tag properly?

Comment: Thank you, Bhanu Tej P. This solved the problem: this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl("assets/images/icon1.svg")